# PHP memory_get_usage() on empty PHP script

Tags: php, memory-management

I decided to take a look at how much memory was being allocated to a few of my PHP scripts, and found it to be peaking at about 130KiB. Not bad, I thought, considering what was going on in the script.

Then, I decided to see what the script started at. I expected something around 32KiB.

I got 121952 bytes instead. After that, I tried testing a completely devoid script:

```
<?php 
echo memory_get_usage();
```

It also started with the same amount of memory allocated.

Now, obviously, PHP is going to allocate some memory to the script before it is run, but this seems a bit excessive.

However, it doesn't seem to be dynamic at all based on how much memory is available to the system at the time. I tried consuming more system memory by opening other processes, but the pre-allocated memory amount stayed the same exact number of bytes.

Is this at all configurable on a per script basis, and how does PHP determine how much it will allocate to each script?

> Using PHP Version 5.4.7

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `memory_get_usage` function directly queries PHP's memory allocator to get this information. It reports how much memory is used by PHP itself, not how much the whole process or even the system as a whole is using.

If you do not pass in an additional `true` argument what you get back is the exact amount of memory that your code uses; this will never be more than what `memory_get_usage(true)` reports.

If you do call `memory_get_usage(true)` you will get back the size of the heap the allocator has reserved from the system, which includes memory that has not been actually used by your code but is directly available to your code.

When your script needs more memory than what is already available to the allocator, the latter will reserve another big chunk from the OS and you will see `memory_get_usage(true)` jump up sharply while `memory_get_usage()` might only increase by a few bytes.

The exact strategy the allocator uses to decide when and how much memory to allocate is baked into PHP at compilation time; you would have to edit the source and compile PHP to change this behavior.

Comment: I passed the true argument, and it returned 262144 bytes now, using the empty code example above.

Comment: @crush: That's not a question, so I 'm not sure how to reply.

Comment: You mentioned that if I pass true to the function, that it would report the exact amount of memory that my code is using. So, please, explain why a completely empty script, with only a call to `memory_get_usage(true);` reports back more than 2x what a script with simply `memory_get_usage();`, which according to you is the total amount allocated to PHP's allocator, reports.

Comment: @crush: Oops, my bad. It's actually the other way around (edited the answer accordingly).

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense! Thanks. Now, that leads to my next question: Can I specify how much to allocate, and why is it allocating such a large block of memory for a single function call?

Comment: Alright, good enough for me. I'll have to play around with spawning thousands of PHP processes, and logging the memory allocations I think anyways. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to tell PHP to allocate more memory to scripts that are more likely to need it, as opposed to allocating it evenly. Similar to changing the way an std::vector allocates memory from n*2 to n+1 (or some other scheme) depending on how you want to use the container.

Comment: @crush: Because that's how the allocator is programmed to work. I added some more information; you can see the C code for yourself [here](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_alloc.c). There is hardly any point in trying to optimize the allocation yourself; if there were real need for that, you 'd be writing code in C.